# crontab not running for Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, cron

## UPDATE 2

This is a documented issue in Fedora 23. I used the workaround listed here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1263328. It looks like it is working.

## UPDATE

I set selinux to permissive mode and now it works. Can somebody lend some insight on what happened?

## ORIGINAL

Using `crontab -e`, I have done this:

```
* * * * * echo test >> /tmp/a.log
```

But nothing seems to happen.

Note: There is a blank line after the line.

### What I have tried

I looked over [this Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) but I could not find a solution. Running

```
ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep
```

gives

```
root       986     1  0 22:07 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/crond -n
```

I don't know what's wrong. Please help.

Comment: Did you create the crontab using the `crontab` command, or by editing a file in `etc`?

Comment: I used crontab -e.

Comment: Are you running cron for root user? If not, look at `/etc/cron.allow` and `/etc/cron.deny` files, if you try to use cron for a non root user, you have to specify it in  `/etc/cron.allow`

Comment: I am not running cron for root. My /etc/cron.deny is empty. I did not have a cron.allow before and adding one with my user does not help.

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by a bug which was resolved by [this update in January, 2016](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2016-b59fd603be).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not working?

```
[nazu@palaceredirect ~]# crontab -l
* * * * * /bin/echo hi >> /tmp/test
[nazu@palaceredirect ~]# ls -l /tmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 nazu nazu    6 Jan 17 20:54 test
```

1. Check your account's mail to see if anything is reporting back. `mail` command.
2. Restart `crond` if you're unsure. `systemctl restart crond.service`
3. You might want to check /etc/cron.deny.

As an aside, you should use the full qualified path of commands in cron. Do it as a habit.

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is not working. I replaced the "echo" with "/bin/echo" but still no dice. I checked both my mail and the root's mail and both are empty. I restarted crond but no change. /etc/cron.deny is an empty folder. I am not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a file to test Cron Job:

```
 $touch echo.sh
```

Enter your script in the file and try it first manually once the script executing properly, you can schedule it for Cronjob.

**Set Permission:**

```
$ chmod +x /path/to/file/echo.sh
```

**Cron Job example:**

```
 crontab -e

* * * * * /path/to/file/echo.sh
```

Save the Entry.

You can also check the output for the cron:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

OR

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
```

Comment: I did as you stated and still no luck. I am using Fedora and I do not have a syslog file. I used `journalctl | grep CRON` and got the following output for today: `Jan 18 09:49:36 localhost.localdomain crond[981]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 93% if used.)
Jan 18 09:49:36 localhost.localdomain crond[981]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Jan 18 10:01:01 localhost.localdomain CROND[4159]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do the following:

- Install some SELinux troubleshooting tools ##

  ```
  yum install setroubleshoot setools
  ```
- Scan the audit.log file and generate a report containing all discovered SELinux issues  ##

  ```
  sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
  ```
- Either address any issues or create a new policy to white list them using the commands provided at the end of the report ##

Answer (score 0):

I battled this issue for a few days, and found that to execute my root cron jobs, simply remove the username from the crontab.

## This seems like unexpected behavior.

An upgrade broke the system, then after a clean install cron failed.  Additionally to make it weirder, when I tried the suggested fix I kept getting bad magic number error :/

```
RESOLUTION:
crontab -l [Success]
* * * * * /mnt/nfs/System/sensorSnapshotLoop.sh

crontab -l [failure]
* * * * * root /mnt/nfs/System/sensorSnapshotLoop.sh
```

Details:

```
201601201546: this cron entry has no username!
test cron:
crontab -e
* * * * * echo test >> /tmp/a.log
crontab -l
systemctl enable crond
systemctl restart crond
systemctl status crond
cat /tmp/a.log
success!

201601201529: ~5 re-installs later trying different suggestions
#mount nfs share
vi /etc/fstab 
192.168.1.77:/System /mnt/nfs/System            nfs     defaults        0 0
reboot

201601191226: reinstall again
OS reinstall
CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso
features:
Server with GUI
    Network File System Client
    Development Tools
security:
    standard system security profile

201601191033: bad magic after clean install?
#https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1263328
gedit mycron.cil
; cron fix
(allow unconfined_t user_cron_spool_t( file ( entrypoint)))
cat mycron.cil
semodule -i mycron.cil
reboot
FAIL! [bad magic number]

#201601190950: still fails w/o nfs access
fix cron <-- no nfs access
mkdir /root/metrics/
cp /mnt/nfs/System/sensorSnapshot.sh /root/metrics/
chmod +x /root/metrics/sensorSnapshotLoop.sh
crontab -e
* * * * * root /root/metrics/sensorSnapshotLoop.sh
crontab -l
systemctl restart crond
systemctl status crond
failed

#201601181929: reinstall/mount nfs share
#mount nfs share
vi /etc/fstab 
192.168.1.77:/System /mnt/nfs/System            nfs     defaults        0 0
reboot

#2016-01-18-1428: noticed failure
upgrade MPSS stack
-> cron failure
*reinstall OS
```

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: If I'm reading your explanation correctly, this seems like **expected* behavior. From the `crontab(5)` man page, _The  jobs  in  cron.d  and /etc/crontab are system jobs, which are used usually for more than one user,  thus,  additionally  the  username  is  needed.user,  thus,  additionally  the  username  is  needed._ That's awkwardly explained, but the point is the `username` field _only_ goes in files in `/etc/cron.d` or the `/etc/crontab` file. But you're not doing that — you're using `crontab -e` to edit the _individual-user crontab file which happens to belong to the root user_.